# Build Google test on Windows use script to Test C Code

Tags: c, windows, googletest

When I build google test on windows use script, why I must follow the order:

```
Step 1: temporary rename sh
Step 2: restore sh
```

Detail code below:

```
    # temporary rename sh
    echo -e "Renaming /usr/bin/sh!!\n\n"
    mv /usr/bin/sh.exe /usr/bin/shx.exe    
    cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" CMakeLists.txt   
    mingw32-make.exe VERBOSE=1
    # restore sh
    echo -e "\n\nRestoring /usr/bin/sh!!\n\n"
    mv /usr/bin/shx.exe /usr/bin/sh.exe
```

The other question is: The reason why I should run this shell with Git Bash (unix env) instead of cmd/powershell?

Comment: Why don't you `#define "sh" "stub-sh"`; one doesn't need root privileges for that.

Comment: You can show me the reason why must follow 2 step above ?

Comment: Maybe `sh` is overridden in the `cmake` by a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_stub because `sh` is integral to the programme, one wants to test different behaviour of `sh`? I actually have not used this testing environment, so I cannot say more, but it seems like a hack.